# How to use realloc() in a function and access the values?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, dereference

I know this question has been answered but I have some more problems with it and I have read the other answers of passing pointer to a pointer but I can't figure out how to access the values or store them.

Also code gives error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void secValue(char **);

void main(){
    char *pointer=(char *)malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    char a;
    int i;
    printf("Enter 1st value \n");
    scanf(" %c",&pointer[0]);
    secValue(&pointer);

    //Display
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
        printf(" %c\n", pointer[i]);
    }
}

void secValue(char **pointera){
    printf("First value is %c \n",*pointera[0]);

    printf("Enter 2nd value\n");
    scanf(" %c",&pointera[1]);

    printf("Enter 3rd and 4th value\n");
    *pointera=(char *)realloc(*pointera,3*sizeof(char));
    scanf(" %c %c",&pointera[2],&*pointera[3]);
}
```

Comment: Sjouldn:'t IT BE 4* Not 3*?

Comment: Should be `&(*pointera)[1]`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Can you help me with what that line exactly means? I am new to programming.

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon i think array starts from 0 , so 0 1 2 3 which makes 4 input. so why do i need to make it 4*?

Comment: @Pratik Because you need 4 elements of `char` size.

Comment: As @RobertS said, the size is 4 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `&((*pointera)[1])` instead of `&pointera[1]` because the second expression is address of second pointer in pointera array, NOT the address of nested pointer address. We must use parentheses because of operator priority.

I also included minor code fixes such as removing redundant pointer casts. C language allows implicit casts from `void *` to other pointer types.

You must also correct argument in `realloc()` function call. You access third array index, so array length must be at least 4.

You must also insert `getchar()` calls after reading each single char by scanf() function, because `scanf()` leaves \n character in stdin, and next call to `scanf()` with %c format will read new line character instead of typed character by you.

So there is your whole code (fixed), I tried not to change logic and even names :P

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void secValue(char **);

int main() {
    char *pointer = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    char a;
    int i;
    printf("Enter 1st value \n");
    scanf("%c", &pointer[0]);
    getchar();
    secValue(&pointer);

    for(i = 0; i <= 3;i++) {
        printf("%c\n", pointer[i]);
    }
}

void secValue(char **pointera) {
    printf("First value is %c\n", (*pointera)[0]);

    printf("Enter 2nd value\n");
    scanf("%c", &((*pointera)[1]));
    getchar();

    printf("Enter 3rd and 4th value\n");
    *pointera = realloc(*pointera, 4 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%c %c", &((*pointera)[2]), &((*pointera)[3]));
}
```

Cheers, gjm

Comment: i need to have a chat with you regarding my project. can you help? also i dont know how to send msg in stackoverflow

Comment: I don't know too, but you can write on my email `vaversky.official@gmail.com`

Comment: `printf(" %c\n", pointer[i]);`is wrong. Should be  `printf(" %c\n", *pointer[i]);` if he wants to display the value of the according array element, not the address of it.

Comment: No man, `pointer[i]` is the value of this pointer (equal to `*(pointer + i)` expression) if the `pointer` variable is first degree pointer (pointer to value).

Comment: @GrzegorzMałyska I have sent you mail

Comment: @Pratik received :)

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
*pointera[0]
```

is equivalent to

```
*( pointera[0] )
```

and yields the value of the object of the type char.

You could rewrite the expression like

```
( *pointera )[0]
```

but the result for this particular case will be the same because `pointera[0]` and `*pointera` are equivalent expressions. You could even write `pointera[0][0]` of `**pointera`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) 
{
    char c = 'A';
    char *p = &c;
    char **q = &p;

    printf( "c = %c\n", *q[0] );
    printf( "c = %c\n", ( *q )[0] );
    printf( "c = %c\n", q[0][0] );
    printf( "c = %c\n", **q );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
c = A
c = A
c = A
c = A
```

However these relations are valid when you are trying to access a single object pointed to by a pointer.

When a pointer points to a pointer that points to the first element of an array then it is better to use the following record

```
( *pointera )[i]
```

where `i` is an index of the required element. This record says the reader of the code that the second pointer `( *pointera )` points to the first element of an array.

So to make your function `secValue` more readable I suggest to substitute the expression in this statement

```
printf("First value is %c \n",*pointera[0]);
```

to the following

```
printf("First value is %c \n", ( *pointera )[0]);
```

As for this statement

```
scanf(" %c",&pointera[1]);
```

then the used expression is already invalid. The pointer `pointera` points to a single object (another pointer) so the expression `pointera[1]` points to beyond the single object. You have to write

```
scanf(" %c", *pointera + 1 );
```

or

```
scanf(" %c", &( *pointera )[1] );
```

The same is valid for this statement

```
scanf(" %c %c",&pointera[2],&*pointera[3]);
```

There shall be either

```
scanf(" %c %c", *pointera + 2, *pointera + 3 );
```

or

```
scanf(" %c %c",&( *pointera )[2],&( *pointera )[3]);
```

It seems in this statement

```
*pointera=(char *)realloc(*pointera,3*sizeof(char));
```

there is a typo. You mean

```
*pointera=(char *)realloc(*pointera, 4 * sizeof(char));
                                    ^^^
```

Also it is better to use an intermediate variable to reallocate memory because `realloc` can return `NULL` and the original pointer `pointera` will be overwritten with `NULL`.

So the function can look like

```
void secValue(char **pointera){
    printf("First value is %c \n", ( *pointera )[0]);

    printf("Enter 2nd value\n");
    scanf(" %c", *pointera + 1 );

    printf("Enter 3rd and 4th value\n");

    char *tmp = realloc(*pointera, 4 * sizeof(char)); 

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        *pointera = tmp 
        scanf(" %c %c",*pointera + 2, *pointera + 3 );
    }
}
```